# Serving gzipped by gulp files on Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, gzip, angular9, firebase-hosting

I've got Angular 9 application which isn't really big enough, but somehow main.js bundle size is 1.7Mb.
There're only few dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.0.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/material": "^9.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.2",
"firebase": "^7.9.3",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.9",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

After `ng-build --prod` function I launch `gulp compress` to gzip all built files:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let gzip = require('gulp-gzip');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./dist/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

[Here I have this list of files in dist directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wl2D.png)

Tried different ways (including serving only .gz files), but I get niether an error nor same size file. Any kind of help would be very usefull, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting automatically compresses with gzip so you shouldn't do it manually.

> Each file that you upload is cached on SSDs at CDN edges around the world and served as gzip or Brotli. We auto-select the best compression method for your content. No matter where your users are, the content is delivered fast.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting

Comment: Yes, I can see in Response Headers that current encoding type is br. But I also noticed that file size in web is exectily the same as on my PC. May be I don't completly understand how all this encoding thing works, but it seems like nothing is compressed.

Comment: It probably depends on what tool you're using to look at the size. Some tools might show the actual size be default instead of the transfer size.